# Spring MessageSource fallback to explicit locale

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

In some spring boot application, i18n is used. Here is the config:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename(translationsPath);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
    return messageSource;
}

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
    localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return localeResolver;
}
```

There is a requirement to obtain a locale from header `Accept-language`, falling back to "en" if:

- the header is missing,
- the header has wrong value,
- the config is missing for the locale.

Two first points are resolved by provided `LocaleResolver` (see config). However, I don't know how to implement point 3: the reloadable list of translation configs is encapsulated in `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`, and I see no way how to make it fall back to "en" locale on some absent config.

There is `setFallbackToSystemLocale` option, but system locale != "en" locale. Moreover, `MessageSource` uses system locale only to resolve the token from translation config, not for localizing the message itself, which causes discrepancies with localizing the numbers.

I might try to limit the list of supported locales by using `setSupportedLocales` on `LocaleResolver`, but it is not suitable solution in my case, since the list of translation configs is supposed to change in runtime.

Is there a way to make `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` fallback to explicit locale?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved that in a bit dirty way by writing a wrapper around `MessageSource`. It is not exactly what was requested: the fallback locale will be used if the token for requested one is absent (which is close but not the same as "config was absent"). Also, it swallows exceptions and uses them for flow control, which is not good.

```
final class FallbackMessageSource implements MessageSource {
    private final MessageSource delegate;
    private final Locale fallbackLocale;

    public FallbackMessageSource(MessageSource delegate, Locale fallbackLocale) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.fallbackLocale = fallbackLocale;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, String defaultMessage, Locale locale) {
        try {
            return delegate.getMessage(code, args, defaultMessage, locale);
        } catch(NoSuchMessageException ex) {
            return delegate.getMessage(code, args, defaultMessage, fallbackLocale);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage(String code, Object[] args, Locale locale) throws NoSuchMessageException {
        try {
            return delegate.getMessage(code, args, locale);
        } catch(NoSuchMessageException ex) {
            return delegate.getMessage(code, args, fallbackLocale);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage(MessageSourceResolvable resolvable, Locale locale) throws NoSuchMessageException {
        try {
            return delegate.getMessage(resolvable, locale);
        } catch(NoSuchMessageException ex) {
            return delegate.getMessage(resolvable, fallbackLocale);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is over a year old, but I was looking to do the same today. This answer was very helpful, but I would suggest a minor edit: The function that accepts a defaultMessage should call getMessage(code, args, locale); in its try block, instead of the defaultMessage version. The given implementation falls back to the defaultMessage immediately, instead of trying the "default locale" first, because it does not actually throw an exception when the code is missing.

In its catch block, it should call the full invocation, including the defaultMessage

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Spring 5.2.2, this will be possible, see [This spring-framework commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/f61d728db9437cf689f942e624a47b4c4c256db0)

Answer (score 1):

There is an useful config **spring.messages.use-code-as-default-message**. When it's true case the code message cannot be found: **<spring:message code="not_found_label"/>** the tag will render the code as default message.

Whether to fall back to the system Locale if no files for a specific Locale have been found. if this is turned off, the only fallback will be the default file (e.g. "messages.properties" for basename "messages").

[Here is the official complete core properties that can be used with spring application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html)

[Here the official docs about <spring:message code="code" text="fallback text"/>](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/1.2.x/taglib/tag/MessageTag.html) It's also possible define a fallback text on text param.

in properties - **application.properties**

```
spring.messages.use-code-as-default-message=true
```

in YML format - **application.yml**

```
spring:  
  messages:
    use-code-as-default-message: true
```

Or a configuration bean:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    return messageSource;
}
```